# Why I can't call user function defined in script tags that uses external library

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Register</title>
<!-- Include CSS File Here -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<!-- Include JS File Here -->
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.7.20.min.js">

    function dispatchRegister() {
       //Some AWS lib code 
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="main">
<h2>Put Your credentials</h2>
<form id="form_id" method="post" name="myform">
<label>registerUsername</label>
<input type="text" name="registerUsername" id="registerUsername"/>
<label>registerPassword</label>
<input type="text" name="registerPassword" id="registerPassword"/>
<label>registerEmail</label>
<input type="text" name="registerEmail" id="registerEmail"/>
<input type="button" value="Register" id="submit" onclick="dispatchRegister()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I got error "*Uncaught ReferenceError: dispatchRegister is not defined*"
I suspect function is not in global scope but how I can get around that?

Comment: You *either* do a `src` attribute *or* you write an inline script. Combining both is not really a thing.

Comment: I can't see answer in duplicated answer, also below explanation is not what I have asked. I didn't asked to show me that simple function works when it is in script code without any src I wanted to run AWS library code. This do not work If have embedded AWS lib code in script tag with src. If I add my code in script tag without src It cannot find AWS libraries.

Comment: The answer is that you need **two `<script>` tags**. One with `src` to import the AWS library, and one without `src` which defines your `dispatchRegister` function. Your current code doesn't work because the latter one is being ignored. If you have some issue beyond that within `dispatchRegister` calling some AWS code you need to be more specific about that.

Comment: Add AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2'; to dispatchRegister function body does it work then?

Answer (score 3):

[Script-tags documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) states about the src-attribute:

*This attribute specifies the URI of an external script; this can be used as an alternative to embedding a script directly within a document. **If a script element has a src attribute specified, it should not have a script embedded inside its tags**.*

So remove the src and add the external script as a separate script-tag:

```html
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.7.20.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function dispatchRegister() {
    console.log("Here I am!");
  }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Register" id="submit" onclick="dispatchRegister()" />
```

Comment: Why this answer has 2 votes it is not what I have asked for? Call some AWS lib code in Your example and You will see it doesn't work

Comment: @user3655463 Erm? You specified the errormessage that states "dispatchRegister is not defined"... And I answered why you get the error message and how to resolve it. Nowhere in ***your question*** (subject tries to hint something but the question doesn't) there is actually a question about a call to external library, so the question is far from clear. Anyway, this answer should resolve ***both*** of your issues ***if*** you don't have some other problem with your code that is not in your example.

Comment: You missed comment about aws lib: try to add AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2'; to function does it work then?

Comment: @user3655463 You should edit the additional information to the question and not add it as a comment. Your question now contradicts with the problem you are facing. The question to your latest comment "does it work" is yes, it does as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/mk1endak/ Everything working as expected. As I said before, you have another problem somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

because you set the src to `src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.7.20.min.js"`

Try to add the `dispatchRegister()` like this and it will work:

```
<script>
function dispatchRegister() {
   //Some AWS lib code 
}
</script>
```